# Replacing a space with underscore in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, 16-bit, as88

```
    _EXIT = 1
    _READ = 3
    _WRITE = 4
    _STDIN = 0
    _STDOUT = 1

    BUFFSIZE = 80
.SECT .TEXT
start:
    PUSH    endpr-prompt    ! print prompt
    PUSH    prompt
    PUSH    _STDOUT     ! on standard output
    PUSH    _WRITE
    SYS
    ADD SP,8        ! clean up stack
    PUSH    BUFFSIZE    ! read input line
    PUSH    buff
    PUSH    _STDIN      ! from standard input
    PUSH    _READ
    SYS
    ADD SP,8        ! clean up stack

    !! assert: AX holds number of bytes that were read
    MOV DX,AX
    ADD DX,buff     ! set DX to addr of first byte after input
    MOV BX,buff     ! initialize loop
1:  !! loop invar: all non-space chars before (BX) have been printed
    CMP BX,DX       ! if unprocessed bytes remain in buff...
    JE  9f
    CMPB    (BX),' '    ! then if next byte is not a space...
    JE  2f
    PUSH    1       ! print that byte
    PUSH    BX
    PUSH    _STDOUT
    PUSH    _WRITE
    SYS
    ADD SP,8
2:  INC BX      ! move to next char of buff
    JMP 1b      ! end of loop


9:  PUSH    0       ! normal exit status
    PUSH    _EXIT       ! end program
    SYS

.SECT .DATA
prompt: .ASCII "Enter input: "
endpr:
size:   .WORD   0       ! length of input

.SECT .BSS
buff:   .SPACE BUFFSIZE
endbuff:
```

Currently, my code removes the space in a string but I cant figure out how to replace it with an new predefined character. I'm completely new to assembly. Any help would be appreciated. How would I assign a character to replace the ' ' character which is removed by using a JE to 2?

Comment: How about instead of branching to the "next-round", you just branch over the normal character printing into blank handling, and at the end of normal character printing you jump over the blank handling to the "next-round"?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? It seems you're making a suggestion on how to modify my handling of the omission of spaces.

Comment: If the next byte is not space, jump to underscore printing after which continue to what's now labeled 2, and after "ADD SP, 8" put a jump that jumps to what is now labeled 2, over the underscore printing. (If-then-else structure.)

Comment: I suppose that's x86 but `SYS` confuses me.

Comment: @cad, they are using [as88](http://sun-java.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~robd/courses/2007/comp202/materials/cdrom/html/8088_tra/linux.htm)